# Form data is not getting saved in MongoDB and it shows no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am new to MongoDB & NodeJS, I created a form using PUG. So when I click on submit nothing really happens, I am not getting any error and my data is also not getting saved in the database. My form is not getting reset, It feels like my submit button is not working. I tried everything but I am not getting anywhere. Even a little help will be appreciated.

PUG

```
extends base.pug

block scripts
    script(src='../static/index.js')
block style 
    style 
        include ../static/style.css
        include ../static/contact.css

block content
    div.contactcontainer 
        h1 Contact Us 
        form(action="/contact", method="post", Class="myForm") 
            input(type="text", Class="myInput", name="name", placeholder="Enter Your Name")
            input(type="phone", Class="myInput", name="phone", placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number")
            input(type="email", Class="myInput", name="email", placeholder="Enter Your Email")
            input(type="text", Class="myInput", name="address", placeholder="Enter Your Address")
            input(type="text", Class="myInput", name="desc", placeholder="Enter Your Concern")
            button(type="button" Class="btn")
                |   Submit
```

---

JS

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/contactus');
const port = 80;

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    phone: Number,
    email: String, 
    address: String,
    desc: String
});

const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);

app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const params = {};
    res.status(200).render('home.pug', params);

})

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    const params = {};
    res.status(200).render('contact.pug', params);

})

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    const mydata = new Contact(req.body);
    mydata.save().then(() => {
        res.send('Saved');
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(400).send('Not Saved');
    });

})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug is not the easiest to work with so [this](https://html2jade.org/) site allows you to convert HTML to PUG/JADE. Your form should look like this:

```
form.myForm(action='/contact' method='post')
  label(for='name') Name: 
  input.myInput(type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter Your Name' required='')
  label(for='phone') Phone: 
  input.myInput(type='phone' name='phone' placeholder='Enter Your Phone Number' required='')
  label(for='email') Email: 
  input.myInput(type='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter Your Email' required='')
  label(for='address') Address: 
  input.myInput(type='text' name='address' placeholder='Enter Your Address' required='')
  label(for='desc') Description: 
  input.myInput(type='text' name='desc' placeholder='Enter Your Concern' required='')
  input(type='submit' value='Submit')
```

You don't need to use `body-parser`. As long as you are using Express v4.16 or greater then `body-parser` comes with Express, you can remove `body-parser`. Include the following:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));
app.use(express.json());
```

These allow you to handle `POST` request data which means you can read from `req.body` in your routes.

Change this:

```
const mydata = new Contact(req.body);
```

To this:

```
const mydata = new Contact({ 
   name: req.body.name,
   phone: req.body.phone,
   email: req.body.email,
   address: req.body.address,
   desc: req.body.desc, 
});
```

When handling user supplied data always try to be explicit with the data you are using from the `req.body` object. A basic hacker could pass any value in the form data and compromise your database. Clearly you will want to validate and sanitize this data but that is beyond this post.

Comment: I just made these changes in the pug template and it started saving data into the database, Thank u so much.

Comment: You're welcome. In my experience [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) or [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) both offer good, user friendly templating you may wish consider as alternatives to pug.